# difference between --executor-memory 12G and --executor-memory 8G --conf spark.yarn.memoryoverhead 4G

Tags: java, apache-spark, scheduler

In the past few days,i have suffered a lot of OOM problems in spark. So i googled how to deal with this problem,some one suggested to boost your overhead memory(size of off heap memory). I know the off heap memory belongs to the system not the jvm ,and My question is : is any difference between  --executor-memory 12G and (--executor-memory 8G --conf spark.yarn.memoryoverhead 4G) ,both of these two configuration allocated 12G memory to program.And is there any possible that some project can run successfully on one of the two configuration ,but will fail on the other one because of the OOM?
Thanks for your time!